Splitt git push to Azure DevOps
I would like ask you for help with git and how to split push to smaller one. I am not experienced in git so I need help.
My problem is that I can't send push bigger than 5GB to Azure DevOps it is reason why I need split push.
I have big push because I am trying reduce repository by removing binary files.
I follow these steps
git clone --bare --mirror
I am using git-filter-repo for reduce repository size.
after that
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250 --max-pack-size=2g
Repository was reduced perfectly and packages are not bigger than 2GB. It does not help with push.
because when I push my changes by
git push origin --force --mirror --prune
I get error about size.
I found solution with counting commits, but it does not work as I supposed. First it raised error that I am on mirror git. I do not know if I change something wrong way If I unset mirror flag from config.
True is that founded code "worked", but it removed some branches. I need solution where I can push everything for all branches.
After my fail i found another code bellow, but I am afraid that it push only one branch (my be I am wrong). This code also need unset mirror flag.
# Split a repository into batches to avoid `pack exceeds maximum allowed size` on git push

REMOTE=origin
BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
BATCH_SIZE=500

# check if the branch exists on the remote
if git show-ref --quiet --verify refs/remotes/$REMOTE/$BRANCH; then
    # if so, only push the commits that are not on the remote already
    range=$REMOTE/$BRANCH..HEAD
else
    # else push all the commits
    range=HEAD
fi
# count the number of commits to push
n=$(git log --first-parent --format=format:x $range | wc -l)

# push each batch
for i in $(seq $n -$BATCH_SIZE 1); do
    # get the hash of the commit to push
    h=$(git log --first-parent --reverse --format=format:%H --skip $i -n1)
    echo "Pushing $h..."
    git push $REMOTE $h:refs/heads/$BRANCH
done

# push the final partial batch
git push $REMOTE HEAD:refs/heads/$BRANCH`

Please can you confirm me if this code does what I need. It means that pushes will be lower than 5GB and that push all my branches only reduced by filter-repo?
Thank you for your help

What is the exact error message you received? Does it contain a numerical size in it?

Also, whether or not your idea will work depends on the content of the commits you are splitting. If all the big files are in a single commit, then splitting the push into smaller sets of commits won't help.

Limit size is 5GB it is in error message. Limit is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/limits?view=azure-devops#push-size. I do not have that big commits. 200Mb is maximal size for my one commit, but it is much less in most cases. So I suppose that counting commits can help.

I did more tests. I used script mentioned in question "# Split a repository into batches to avoid pack exceeds maximum allowed size on git push". Because I don't want destroy my orig repository I did duplicate and I tried script duplicate repositories. I had to unset mirror.The script copied only one branch somehow choosed by clone command.So I changed the script and I used git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" --sort='authordate'  for running over all branches. I had to check if branch name content 'refs/heads/' and for these branches I did split pushes. It worked and created all branches.

Problem is that all branches are same. It looks like that branch choosed by git clone was pushed to all branches. I hope that I can somehow use command git log for get branches with their commits. I tried git log --first-parent 'origin/branchname', but I get error fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/branchname': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. When I tried same command with git log --first-parent 'branchnamechoosedbyclone' it worked. I suppose that reason why I get this error is that I cloned repository with --mirror, but I need it for filter-repo.

Hi @Fido, I found a same question about pushing a Git mirror in chunks. Can you please check if it helps the issue?

Hi @MiaoTian-MSFT, I tried suggested push, but without success. I get error message about limit. I see that in responses is mentioned counting for commits. I feel that it same as script that I used and modified. The script worked and created all branches, but with same content. I hope that it will be small problem that can be solved by git log command or something similar and after that it will work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I though that I describe detailed as I could. I need Git commands that clone repository, reduce binary files by git filter-repo and push back to Azure DevOps by small pushes lower then 5GB.

I found solution finally. I used founded script mentioned in question. I used git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" --sort='authordate' for loop over branches. I had to add git symbolic-ref HEAD BRANCH to my code for switch branch in bare repository. After that git log returns correct commits for each branch. I had to create new remote for pushes because origin remote created strange results for git log. After that everything works as I expected

Hi @MiaoTian-MSFT I transformed script to PowerShell. So if it is ok for you I can share this script.

Hi @Fido, PowerShell scripts are also great. Thank you and looking forward to your sharing!

I used my split pushes two times in my script. First for backup repository to new one. Second for push changed commits from git filter-repo. I exctracted and rewrite my backup script and added here as solution.
    [string] $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK = "C:\Repositories\bare_clone"
    [string] $RepositoryHttpsURL = "URLToRepository"
    [string] $BackupRepositoryHttpsURL = "URLToBackupRepository"
    [string] $remoteName = "origin"
    [int] $maxPushSizeInMB = (5 * 1024) # 5GB - Azure DevOps limit for one Push
    [int] $splitPushCommitsCount = 100
    [boolean] $splitPush = $false

    $ALocation = Get-Location
    if ($null -ne (Test-Path $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK)) {
        write-host "Remove directory $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK" -ForegroundColor Green
        $null = Remove-Item $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    }
    write-host "Clone bare repository from $RepositoryHttpsURL to $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK" -ForegroundColor Green
    git clone --bare --mirror $RepositoryHttpsURL $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK

    write-host "Backup repository" -ForegroundColor Magenta

    write-host "Switch to folder $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK" -ForegroundColor green
    Set-Location $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK -ErrorAction Stop

    $doSplitPush = $splitPush #Split push if it is forced
    if (!($doSplitPush)) {
        # check if repository is lower than limit if not do split push
        write-host "git count-objects -vH" -ForegroundColor Green
        $gitCountResult = (git count-objects -vH)
        $splitRegEx = "^(?<Name>[^\s-]+(-[^\s-]+)*):\s*(?<Value>\d+\.?\d*)\s*(?<Measure>\S+)?$"
        $repositorySize = 0
        $gitCountResult | ForEach-Object {
            write-host $_ -ForegroundColor Green
            if ($_ -match $splitRegEx) {
                if ($matches['Name'] -eq 'size-pack') {
                    if ("$($matches['Measure'])" -ne '') {
                        if (($matches['Measure']) -eq 'bytes') {
                            $repositorySize = ([math]::Round((([float]($matches['Value'])) / 1024 / 1024)))
                        }
                        elseif (($matches['Measure']) -eq 'KiB') {
                            $repositorySize = ([math]::Round(([float]($matches['Value']) / 1024)))
                        }
                        elseif (($matches['Measure']) -eq 'MiB') {
                            $repositorySize = ([float]($matches['Value']))
                        }
                        elseif (($matches['Measure']) -eq 'GiB') {
                            $repositorySize = (([float]($matches['Value'])) * 1024)
                        }
                        else {
                            $repositorySize = ([float]($matches['Value']))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $doSplitPush = ($repositorySize -ge $maxPushSizeInMB)
    }

    if (!($doSplitPush)) {
        write-host "Push all to remote repository" -ForegroundColor Magenta
        write-host "git push --mirror $BackupRepositoryHttpsURL" -ForegroundColor Green
        git push --mirror $BackupRepositoryHttpsURL
    }
    else {
        write-host "Splited git pushes to remote repository. Push per $($splitPushCommitsCount) commits" -ForegroundColor Magenta
        if ((git config remote.origin.mirror) -eq "true") {
            write-host "git config --unset remote.origin.mirror" -ForegroundColor Green
            git config --unset remote.origin.mirror
        }
        # Split a repository into batches to avoid `pack exceeds maximum allowed size` on git push
        $REMOTE = $remoteName
        $NewREMOTE = "new_$($remoteName)"
        $BATCH_SIZE = $splitPushCommitsCount
        write-host "Get list of remotes" -ForegroundColor green
        $Remotes = git remote -v

        if ($Remotes) {
            $RemoteExtists = ($null -ne ($Remotes | Where-Object { $_.IndexOf($BackupRepositoryHttpsURL) -ne -1 } ))
            if (!$RemoteExtists) {
                if ($null -ne ($Remotes | Where-Object { $_.IndexOf($NewREMOTE) -ne -1 } )) {
                    write-host "Set existing remote $($NewREMOTE) for $($BackupRepositoryHttpsURL)" -ForegroundColor green
                    git remote set-url "$NewREMOTE" "$BackupRepositoryHttpsURL" | Out-Null
                }
                else {
                    write-host "Add remote $NewREMOTE for $BackupRepositoryHttpsURL" -ForegroundColor green
                    git remote add "$NewREMOTE" "$BackupRepositoryHttpsURL" | Out-Null
                }
            }
        }
        git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" --sort='authordate' | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_.IndexOf("refs/heads/") -ne -1) {
                $BRANCH = $_.Replace("refs/heads/", '')
                write-host "Pushing branch $($BRANCH)" -ForegroundColor yellow
                write-host "Switch $BRANCH" -ForegroundColor green
                write-host "git symbolic-ref HEAD $($_)" -ForegroundColor green
                git symbolic-ref HEAD $_ | Out-Null

                # check if the branch exists on the remote
                if ($null -ne (git show-ref --quiet --verify "refs/remotes/$($NewREMOTE)/$($BRANCH)")) {
                    # check if the branch exists on the remote
                    $range = "$($NewREMOTE)/$($BRANCH)..HEAD"
                }
                else {
                    # else push all the commits
                    $range = "HEAD"
                }
                write-host "Range $($range)" -ForegroundColor green
                # count the number of commits to push
                $n = (git log --first-parent --format="format:x $range").Length
                write-Host "Count of commits to push $($n)" -ForegroundColor green
                if ($n -gt 0) {
                    $loopCount = [int] [Math]::Truncate($n / $BATCH_SIZE)
                    # push each batch
                    for ($i = 1; $i -le $loopCount; $i++) {
                        $h = git log --first-parent --reverse --format=format:%H --skip ($n - ($i * $BATCH_SIZE)) -n1
                        write-Host "Skip commits $(($n - ($i * $BATCH_SIZE))) to $($h)" -ForegroundColor green
                        Write-Host "Pushing $($NewREMOTE) --force $($h):refs/heads/$($BRANCH)"
                        git push "$($NewREMOTE)" --force "$($h):refs/heads/$($BRANCH)"
                    }
                    # push last batch
                    Write-Host "Pushing $($NewREMOTE)" --force "HEAD:refs/heads/$($BRANCH)"
                    git push "$($NewREMOTE)" --force "HEAD:refs/heads/$($BRANCH)"
                }
                else {
                    write-host "Skiped push no commits" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                }
            }
        }
        write-host "git push $NewREMOTE --force 'refs/tags/*'" -ForegroundColor Green
        git push $NewREMOTE --force 'refs/tags/*'
        write-host "git push $NewREMOTE --force 'refs/replace/*'" -ForegroundColor Green
        git push $NewREMOTE --force 'refs/replace/*'
    }
    Set-Location $ALocation
    if (Test-Path -Path $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK) {
        write-host "Remove directory $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK" -ForegroundColor Green
        $null = Remove-Item $RepositoryFolderPathForBareCloneBAK -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    }

